# Jetpack Compose Button with custom shape

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create the Button shape customized using the Jetpack compose, this is the example, of how it looks like:

[image: Custom Button]

I don't know how to create this kind of shape for the button, like it's been little top little rounded and also it is rounded in the bottom as well.

How can I create this element in the Jetpack compose?

Comment: I would recommend you use GenericShape() or create your own class that extands class Shape() here is a little guide : https://juliensalvi.medium.com/custom-shape-with-jetpack-compose-1cb48a991d42

Comment: @AymanAit why didn't you answer? It is absolutely relevant and correct answer

Comment: @Mike well i didn't answer because i think my answer is more of a general solution not specific to how to create the exact shape he wants soooo....